Bank not received international transfer threatening to take money back
I'm having an issue with my bank:
I received money from abroad (paid via revolut in Lithuania afaik) to my UK bank (the cooperative bank)
The money was credited to my account and all seemed fine until a few days later when I got an email from the "foreign" department saying they hadn't actually received the payment and if they didn't in the next 5 days they'd take the money out of my account.
I got in touch with the sender, who got in touch with their bank and has sent me a pdf of the transactions for the transfer and I'm trying to understand what has happened and how to fix it.
On the pdf it shows that jo Morgan chase rejected the cover but I don't know what that means or if it matters. It shows my bank received the money but they're saying they didn't.
A few days after thr first email my bank account got attacked by fraud, and was drained. Most of the money has been recovered but it's obviously very weird and makes me wonder if their systems have been compromised to not have accurate records and to let 100s of transactions go through in a short amount of time without fraud detection kicking in.
Any advice on what could be the issue on the international payment, and what I'm allowed to do? What happens if I just transfer the money for example? Are they allowed to take it back?
Thanks

Have tried to get in touch with your bank? Clearly you've been scammed, but it seems like you haven't actually talked to your own bank

I have both the foreign payments department and the fraud department. Foreign payments just say they're looking into it and fraud say they may or may not find/return the money

So what's your question then? You gave your scammer your bank details and they tried to clear you out. Seems like your bank was able to detect the fraud.

No they're two different things but I see I've written it like they're the same. Foreign payment is an invoice from a client I've worked with for over a year. The fraud I don't know. My question is can they take the foreign payment back, do I have other options or just have to wait and see if they find the money

By the way, when I say "contact your bank" I mean literally calling the phone number on the back of your card, not answering phone calls or emails you think are from the bank.

I don't. When I got the email about foreign payments I thought it was a scam so first thing I did was call the bank who confirmed it was real.

You called a number. Who gave you the number? How do you know it is your bank you called? The number on the back of your card is your bank. You said you worked with someone for a year. How many payments did actually go through?

I called the number for customer service from the banks website and every previous payment has gone through, invoicing monthly

"I got in touch with the sender, who got in touch with their bank and has sent me a pdf of the transactions for the transfer" I'm sure you are aware that forging/generating such a pdf with headers and footers that look like a genuine pdf from a real bank is a matter of minutes with the right tools..
